# How to delete kibana logo during loading?

Tags: kibana

Do you know how to delete or replace the kibana logo during loading as shown in the following picture ?
[image]

Indeed, I am importing through iframe links some graphs in my page web and I want to disable this feature.

Thanks.
Regards,

S

Comment: I am using Kibana4.5.1

Comment: Probably against their terms of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference to the markup for the loading indicator: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/ui/views/ui_app.jade#L26

You will need to do this within Kibana unless it's on the same domain do to the cross-origin policy. A plugin would most likely be the easiest/cleanest route.

Answer (score 4):

For all those searching for the solution in **Kibana 6.1**, Here it is

**Display Message Part:**

- Navigate to `src/core_plugins/kibana/translations/en.json` file
- Change value of `UI-WELCOME_MESSAGE` to what you want it to be.

**The Logo Part:**

- Navigate to `src/ui/views/ui_app.jade` file
- Change `background-image` of the css class named `.kibanaWelcomeLogo` to the image url of your own.

Save your edits and restart Kibana and you are done.

Have a good day!